# ipad responsive design restrictions

Tags: iphone, ipad, user-interface

I'm designing a multiplatform, multidevice app using PhoneGap.

The main target are smartphones, but tablets will also be supported, so I'm using an html/css responsive design to accomplish this.

The app functionality requires little text and a few forms with not so many fields, that's great for a smartphone, but with the huge space available on tablets, there's just too much blank space.

For example, this:

[image: smartPhone layout]

Translates into this:

[image: tablet layout]

My main concern is rejection by Apple from the AppStore because of this. Does anyone has experience/suggestions in this case?

Or any design alternatives for this small forms and scarce content on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good way of handling it and you certainly won't get rejected from the App Store for the responsive layout you're showing in your screenshots.